# Java rename not working

Tags: java, file, netbeans

Here is my code

```
private void edit(String search_bookname) {
    String current_bookname ="", current_ISBN = "", current_author = "", current_rating = "", record = "", comma = ",", current_status = "";
    int flag1 = 0, flag2 = 0;
    File file = new File("Book_data.txt");
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file));
        File f = new File("Book_data_copy.txt");
        FileWriter create = new FileWriter(f);
        PrintWriter y = new PrintWriter(create);
        while(reader.ready())
        {
            record = reader.readLine();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(record, ",");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                current_bookname = st.nextToken();
                current_author = st.nextToken();
                current_ISBN = st.nextToken();
                current_rating = st.nextToken();
                current_status = st.nextToken();
                flag2 = 0;
                if (search_bookname.equals(current_bookname)) {
                    flag1 = 1;
                    flag2 = 1;
                    try {
                        y.print(current_bookname); y.print(comma);
                        y.print(current_author); y.print(comma);
                        y.print(current_ISBN); y.print(comma);
                        y.print(current_rating); y.print(comma);
                        y.println("Borrowed");
                    } catch(Exception e) {}
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
             }
     if(flag2==0) // All non-matching records shall only be written to file. Record to be deleted will not be written to new file
                    {
                    y.print(current_bookname);  y.print(comma);      //One record per line.....   Each field in a record is seperated by COMMA (" , " )
                    y.print(current_author);  y.print(comma);
                    y.print(current_ISBN);  y.print(comma);
                    y.print(current_rating);y.print(comma);
                    y.println(current_status);
                     }
    }
        reader.close();
        y.close();
        create.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
    if(flag1==1)     //Rename File ONLY when record has been found for Edit
    {
        File oldFileName = new File("Book_data_copy.txt");  
        File newFileName = new File("Book_data.txt");  
        System.out.println("File renamed .....................");
        try 
        {  
            newFileName.delete();  oldFileName.renameTo(newFileName);
            if (oldFileName.renameTo(newFileName)) 
           System.out.println("File renamed successfull !");  
            else    
            System.out.println("File rename operation failed !"); 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (Exception e) {}

    }
}
```

The project is for a library system. I am relatively new to java and I use netbeans on windows 8.1. The code outputs rename operation failed. Almost exactly the same code for edit has been used before in the program and it worked.

Any suggestions or code corrections would be helpfu.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-)? It might help you: "*Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful*."

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the below code section

```
 oldFileName.renameTo(newFileName);
            if (oldFileName.renameTo(newFileName))
```

you are trying to rename twice. The first might pass but the 2nd will definitely fail. Check if the original file was renamed. If any error is thrown pring the stack trace and add the trace to your post.

Comment: But `File`'s `.delete()` and `.renameTo()` will _never_ throw any exception! They can only return booleans, which makes you none the wiser as to why the operation fails. Which is why any code written with Java 7+ should use the new file API if the programmer is serious about file handling.

Comment: @fge - never is a strong word. It does throw NPE and Security Exception which helps catch permission based issues. However I agree hat nio packages are a better option when not dealing with legacy code.

Comment: Eh? Sorry but it has never thrown a `SecurityException` on me, nor an NPE for that matter. It _can_ throw a `SecurityException` if you have restricted API access in the security manager, not on filesystem/permission errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to rename `oldFileName` twice:

```
newFileName.delete();  oldFileName.renameTo(newFileName); // rename
if (oldFileName.renameTo(newFileName)) // rename again ?!
    System.out.println("File renamed successfull !");  
else    
    System.out.println("File rename operation failed !");
```

The second rename in the if() fails, because the file was renamed already in the line before.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of problems here, starting with ignoring exceptions; not closing the file in a `finally` block; and using `Reader.ready()` incorrectly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how it is used incorrectly or provide some sample code?

Answer (score -1):

This is 2015. [Use `java.nio.file`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API)!

```
final Path srcFile = Paths.get("Book_data.txt").toAbsolutePath();
final Path dstFile = srcFile.resolveSibling("Book_data_copy.txt");

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(srcFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dstFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
) {
    // work with reader and pw
}

if (flag1 == 1)
    Files.move(dstFile, srcFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
        StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

If you did that from the start, not only would your resources have been closed safely (your code doesn't do that) but you would have gotten a meaningful exception as well (you are trying to rename twice; you would have had a `NoSuchFileException` on the second rename).

[Relying on `File` is an error](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks), and it has always been.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the code that you gave doesn't work. It still comes up with the same problem.

Comment: Sure, but did you look at the error message? Now you should have the _real_ cause of the problem; unlike with `.renameTo()`.

Comment: Yeah. I got an AccessDeniedException.

Comment: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\nihar_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\library1\Book_data_copy.txt -> C:\Users\nihar_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\library1\Book_data.txt
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:301)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)

Comment: Is the file opened by another process by any chance (maybe Netbeans itself)? If you have write access to the directory but you can't rename and get this exception, it pretty much always means that